# How can I set the conversionPattern for a Log4Net Console Appender to clear the screen?

Tags: log4net

I want my console appender to clear out the screen before each new write so there is only 1 msg displaying at a time.  I have a second file appender to show the history.
I was hoping for something like this:

```
  <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender"
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="cls%newline %date %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Thank you in advance. -Dustin

Answer (score 2):

If there is an escape sequence of any sort that will clear the screen, then try something like this:

```
<appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender"
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{cls} %date %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

and then in your code before you configure log4net, set the log4net property "cls":

```
string cls = "escape-sequence-here";
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["cls"] = cls;
```

where you assign the appropriate escape sequence to the string variable `cls`.